# LuaJIT and C++ - call to Table.Method() does not work in loadstring/pcall

Tags: c++, lua, luajit

I got 2 functions that register Lua table and method in C++:

```
void LuaScriptInterface::registerTable(const std::string& tableName)
{
    // _G[tableName] = {}
    lua_newtable(luaState);
    lua_setglobal(luaState, tableName.c_str());
}

void LuaScriptInterface::registerMethod(const std::string& globalName, const std::string& methodName, lua_CFunction func)
{
    // globalName.methodName = func
    lua_getglobal(luaState, globalName.c_str());
    lua_pushcfunction(luaState, func);
    lua_setfield(luaState, -2, methodName.c_str());

    // pop globalName
    lua_pop(luaState, 1);
}
```

It registers some methods:

```
registerTable("Game");
// Game.getHouses()
registerMethod("Game", "getHouses", LuaScriptInterface::luaGameGetHouses);
```

Then I call in Lua:

```
local param = "print( Game.getHouses() )"
pcall(loadstring(param))
```

I got problem with **param**. Calls and results:

```
1. print(Game.getHouses())
2. print(Game['getHouses']())
3. print( Game.getHouses() ) -- added spaces
4. print( Game['getHouses']() ) -- added spaces
5. local var = Game.getHouses() print(#var)
6. local var = Game['getHouses']() print(#var)
7. local var = #Game.getHouses() print(var)
8. local var = #Game['getHouses']() print(var)
9. local var = # Game.getHouses() print(var) -- added space
```

Results:

```
1. attempt to call a nil value
2. table: 0x4351fdd0
3. table: 0x42ce6b88
4. table: 0x426513c0
5. 1010
6. 1010 
7. attempt to call a nil value
8. 1010
9. 1010
```

Can anyone tell me a reason, why it does not work in *loadstring/pcall*?

Can I make it work in *loadstring/pcall* somehow?

**EDIT:**

**After 2 hours of debugging. I found out, that client that I use to communicate with server - that executes LUA - does some regex on string that I send (I still don't know why, but it's not LUA related)** :)

Comment: Reduce this to just the code that replicates your problem, there's way too much noise there to see what you're trying to do.

Comment: I need to explain what I did to go into that problem. Maybe I initialize it wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you tried to represent is that `someTable.key` gives a different result than `someTable["key"]` but this cant be possible:

> But it's so common to use string constants as keys there's a special shortcut syntax for it:
>
> ```
> > t = {}
> > t.foo = 123 -- same as t["foo"] (but not t[foo], which would use the variable foo as the key)
> > = t.foo
> 123
> > = t["foo"]
> 123
> ```
>
> The shortcut syntax is only valid if the string consists of underscores, letters, and numbers, but shouldn't start with a number. (http://lua-users.org/wiki/TablesTutorial)

Supported by the fact that it works when not used in `loadstring`, I suspect that your problem is rather with `Player(cid)` `player:getId()` or `"player:getPosition()"`. Important to notice that you are accessing player at two different times. 1. Directly as `player:getId()` and 2. though `loadstring / pcall`. The last possibility would be the `Player(cid)`. One of them is propably not correctly initialized / declared.

I think because of different test conditions your second attempt `local param = "print( #Game['getHouses']() )"`
 worked.

Comment: After you sent you answer, I debugged everything again. I found out that client that I use to communicate with server does replace some characters combinations in text I send. Thanks for help!